# TextView scrollbar doesn't want to move

Tags: android

I enabled scrollbars in `TextView`. It shows but it doesn't move. I can pull as much as I want on screen and nothing scrolls. Why?

This is the activity. X1 should scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/X1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/X2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:text="eroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpo"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/X2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:text="erdiofghjwe riuogfwejrhipgf eripofg jwerpiogf jerpiofg jwrepiogf jwrepigo wjrepr g serdpoi gjweprio gerdiofghjwe riuogfwejrhipgf eripofg jwerpiogf jerpiofg jwrepiogf jwrepigo wjrepr g serdpoi gjweprio gerdiofghjwe riuogfwejrhipgf "
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to search for this but everyone says scrollbars attribute should enable scrolling but I didn't see anyone having issue that scroll is there but is literally frozen.

Comment: what you want is to scroll textview only right .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.!

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/x1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/X2"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:maxLines="3" 
            android:text="eroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpoeroipg jfweropi gfjweroip gfjwpoier gfjwporei gjpwoire jgwpo"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
```

and in your `MainActivty` all you have to do is add this line of code.!

```
x1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to do it without setting maxLines. I want the TextView to take as much space as it's avaiilable.

Comment: Actually, I see it works also without maxLines. Great! Thank you!